# How to get real absolute path with node.js path module

Tags: node.js, path

Running below code brings me path without project folder

```
const path = require('path') 
const absolutepath = path.resolve(argv.directory)
```

`D:\packages\example\dist`

However real absolute path is

```
D:\project\packages\example\dist
```

Can someone help me , why I cant get project folder in absolute path

Answer (score 1):

Simply with :

`__dirname`

Example :

`console.log( __dirname )`